# How to soft delete many to many relation with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django project, all entities deleted by the user must be soft deleted by setting the current datetime to deleted_at property. My model looks like this: Trip <-> TripDestination <-> Destination (many to many relation). In other words, a Trip can have multiple destinations.

When I delete a Trip, the SoftDeleteManager filters out all the deleted trip. However, if I request all the destinations of a trip (using get_object_or_404(Trip, pk = id)), I also get the deleted ones (i.e. TripDestination models with deleted_at == null OR deleted_at != null). I really don't understand why since all my models inherit from LifeTimeTracking and are using the SoftDeleteManager.

Can someone please help me to understand why the SoftDeleteManager isn't working for n:m relation?

```
class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        query_set = super(SoftDeleteManager, self).get_query_set()
        return query_set.filter(deleted_at__isnull = True)

class LifeTimeTrackingModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null = True)

    objects = SoftDeleteManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Destination(LifeTimeTrackingModel):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)

class Trip(LifeTimeTrackingModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    destinations = models.ManyToManyField(Destination, through = 'TripDestination')

class TripDestination(LifeTimeTrackingModel):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination)
```

**Resolution**
I filed the bug [17746](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17746) in Django Bug DB. Thanks to Caspar for his help on this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this behaviour comes from the ManyToManyField choosing to use its own manager, which the [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/) mentions, because when I try making up some of my own instances & try soft-deleting them using your model code (via the manage.py shell) everything works as intended.

<strike>Unfortunately it doesn't mention how you can override the model manager. I spent about 15 minutes searching through the ManyToManyField source but haven't tracked down where it instantiates its manager (looking in django/db/models/fields/related.py).</strike>

To get the behaviour you are after, you should specify `use_for_related_fields = True` on your `SoftDeleteManager` class as specified by the documentation on [controlling automatic managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-types):

```
class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        query_set = super(SoftDeleteManager, self).get_query_set()
        return query_set.filter(deleted_at__isnull = True)
```

This works as expected: I'm able to define a `Trip` with 2 `Destination`s, each through a `TripDestination`, and if I set a `Destination`'s `deleted_at` value to `datetime.datetime.now()` then that `Destination` no longer appears in the list given by `mytrip.destinations.all()`, which is what you are after near as I can tell.

**However**, the docs also specifically say [don't filter the query set by overriding `get_query_set()` on a manager used for related fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#don-t-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass), so if you run into problems later, bear this in mind as a possible cause.

Comment: @Martin I've updated my answer, please see if it works for you :)

Comment: Hello Caspar! Thanks for helping me out. But what I am looking for is to not see the destinations if the Tripdesrimation has been deleted, not Destination.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I tried it and it doesn't work with my solution, which I would think indicates a bug. A [quick search](https://code.djangoproject.com/search?q=use_for_related_fields) through the bugs db doesn't turn anything up (though there is a bug which is [almost the opposite](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14891)), so might be time to raise a bug then.

Comment: Are you familiar with their process? Should we file a bus as well? I am surprised because the bug you pointed me out was opened more than a year ago and still no resolution.

Comment: I filed a new bug on this. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17746. Feel free to update it. Thanks Caspar.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with [their process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/internals/contributing/) but your bug looks good to me, though it was already closed as a duplicate of the one I pointed out! I guess they consider it the same issue of "use_for_related_fields doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

To enable filtering by `deleted_at` field of `Destinantion` and `Trip` models setting `use_for_related_fields = True` for `SoftDeleteManager` class is enough. As per Caspar's answer this does not return deleted `Destinations` for `trip_object.destinations.all()`.

However from your comments we can see you would like to filter out `Destinations` that are linked to `Trip` via a `TripDestination` object with a set `deleted_at` field, a.k.a. soft delete on a *through* instance.

Let's clarify the way managers work. Related managers are the managers of the remote model, not of a through model.

`trip_object.destinantions.some_method()` calls default `Destination` manager.
`destinantion_object.trip_set.some_method()` calls default `Trip` manager.
`TripDestination` manager is not called at any time.

You can call it with `trip_object.destinantions.through.objects.some_method()`, if you really want to. Now, what I would do is add an Instance method `Trip.get_destinations` and a similar `Destination.get_trips` that filters out deleted connections.

If you insist on using the manager to do the filtering it gets more complicated:

```
class DestinationManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        query_set = super(DestinationManager, self).get_query_set()
        if hasattr(self, "through"):
            through_objects = self.through.objects.filter(
                destination_id=query_set.filter(**self.core_filters).get().id,
                trip_id=self._fk_val,
                deleted_at__isnull=True)
            query_set = query_set.filter(
                id__in=through_objects.values("destination_id"))

        return query_set.filter(deleted_at__isnull = True)
```

The same would have to be done for `TripManager` as they would differ. You may check the performance and look at `django/db/models/fields/related.py` for reference.

Modifying the `get_queryset` method of the default manager may hamper the ability to backup the database and the documentation discourages it. Writing a `Trip.get_destinations` method is the alternative.